# Call telemetryclient from azure api policy

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management, azureportal, telemetry

How to call TelemetryClient trackevent within azure api policy.

To log all unhandled and custom exception and informative logging from azure api policy to application insights.

Answer (score 0):

If it's about Azure API Management policies - it's not possible at the moment to log custom telemetry to AI, but AI integration is there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-app-insights, and it should by default log any request processing exceptions.